# Which GTK libgio API's will allow a GATT client to read/write a characteristic?

Tags: gtk, d-bus, bluez

I would like to connect with multiple similar BLE devices simultaneously, with one task (thread) accessing each device.

I do:

```
g_dbus_connection_signal_subscribe(...,"InterfacesAdded",...)
```

The callback for this function then starts a new task for each BLE device passing in the device path.

Then the new thread does:

```
g_dbus_connection_call_sync(...,"org.bluez.Device1","Connect",...).
```

This causes a set of characteristics to appear in my original main loop thread which did the "InterfacesAdded" callback.  If required, I could notify the thread handling the server (remote) device that a new characteristic has appeared.

What libgio API's are used to read and write values to characteristics for BLE? I have not been able to find any sources for this.

I could put a table of DBUS paths in the program for each characteristic I care about.  Or should I somehow look up the UUID?  The characteristics are fixed.

Comment: So far I have found zero examples of libgio and GATT.  Seems like an ideal match.